# How to pass JSON object to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object representing a hierarchy of digital wallets:

```
masterWallets = {wallet: {}, childs: [{}, {}, ..., {}]}
```

the array of childs are other wallets which can contains other wallets... (like a file system).

Here is my html table:

```
<% masterWallets.forEach(function(masterWallet) { %>
      <tr>
        <td>masterWallet.wallet.walletName</td>
        <td><%= JSON.stringify(masterWallet.childs) %></td>
        <td>
           <script>
             document.write(window.getChilds( <%= masterWallet.childs %> ));
           </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% }); %>
```

I would like to pass the array of child wallets (masterWallet.childs) to a function and extract and print some infos. I can see all the childs with:
    <%= JSON.stringify(mWallet.childs) %>
But I can't pass this variable to my function. I have in the javascript console:

```
document.write(window.getChilds( [object Object],[object Object] ));
```

with this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Question: How do I pass a JSON object (or an array of JSON objects ?) to a function ?

Comment: You should pass the `JSON String` then parse it using `Javascript`...

Comment: Have you tried `window.getChilds( <%= JSON.stringify(masterWallet.childs) %> )`?

Comment: "JSON object" is a contradiction. If it's JSON then it's a string. If it's an object then it isn't JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```js
If your masterWallets is an object of wallet and childs then;

    masterWallets = {wallet: {}, childs: [{wallet:{},childs[{}...{n}]}, ..., {n}]}
<% masterWallets.childs.forEach(function(wallet) { %>
      <tr>
        <td>masterWallets.wallet.walletName</td>
        <td><%= JSON.stringify(wallet.childs) %></td>
        <td>
           <script>
             document.write(window.getChilds( <%= wallet.childs %> ));
           </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% }); %>

But if your masterWallets is a collection of wallets then;

 masterWallets = {{wallet: {}, childs: [{}, {}, ..., {n}]},{wallet: {}, childs: [{}, {}, ..., {n}]}};
<% masterWallets.forEach(function(walletObj) { %>
      <tr>
        <td>walletObj.walet.walletName</td>
        <td><%= JSON.stringify(walletObj.childs) %></td>
        <td>
           <script>
             document.write(window.getChilds( <%= walletObj.childs %> ));
           </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: The second option is right: masterWallets is a collection (array) of wallets

Comment: Can you create a  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? So we can debug in the debugger.

Comment: if I do: <%= walletObj.childs %>  it is replace by a string: "[object Object],[object Object]" (in the function I print the typeOf and it gives me String)
If I do JSON.stringify(mWallet.childs) the data are stringify and all the double quotes are replaced by &#34; So, in my function I restored the double quotes and then I did JSON.parse and I got back the JSON object. Now it works! It is possible to pass directly the JSON object to the function?